# Custom cursor doesn't allow click? JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a custom cursor for certain elements of my site, the only issue I'm having is that although it works fine, I can no longer click elements. Anybody know what might be causing this?

http://codepen.io/liamgallagher/pen/MmprwR

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
  alert('sad');
});

(function() {
  var follower, init, mouseX, mouseY, positionElement, printout, timer;

  follower = document.getElementById('follower');

  printout = document.getElementById('printout');

  mouseX = (function(_this) {
    return function(event) {
      return event.clientX;
    };
  })(this);

  mouseY = (function(_this) {
    return function(event) {
      return event.clientY;
    };
  })(this);

  positionElement = (function(_this) {
    return function(event) {
      var mouse;
      mouse = {
        x: mouseX(event),
        y: mouseY(event)
      };
      follower.style.top = mouse.y + 'px';
      return follower.style.left = mouse.x + 'px';
    };
  })(this);

  timer = false;

  window.onmousemove = init = (function(_this) {
    return function(event) {
      var _event;
      _event = event;
      return timer = setTimeout(function() {
        return positionElement(_event);
      }, 1);
    };
  })(this);

}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 6):

Your custom cursor is preventing mouse clicks from reaching the underlying page.

There's no need to hack around with z-indexes or actively hiding/revealing the cursor to solve this; `pointer-events` exists for this purpose:

```
#follower {
    pointer-events: none
}
```

Any pointer (mouse or touch) events will now fall through to whatever is behind your custom cursor.  Note that this includes `:hover` events, so the standard hover cursor will appear on links unless you suppress it;  for example:

```
a:hover {cursor: none}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer @DanielBeck - How would I hide the cursor however with pointer-events on?

Comment: @Liam, Sure thing, adding that to the answer now.

Answer (score 2):

Add `z-index: -1` to `#follower`. A non-static `position` on `#follower` gives that element a default `z-index` when everything else is statically positioned so nothing else has a `z-index`. That stacking order means when you click, you're just clicking on the `#follower` element.

```js
$('a').on('click',function(){
  alert('sad');
});

(function() {
  var follower, init, mouseX, mouseY, positionElement, printout, timer;

  follower = document.getElementById('follower');

  printout = document.getElementById('printout');

  mouseX = (function(_this) {
    return function(event) {
      return event.clientX;
    };
  })(this);

  mouseY = (function(_this) {
    return function(event) {
      return event.clientY;
    };
  })(this);

  positionElement = (function(_this) {
    return function(event) {
      var mouse;
      mouse = {
        x: mouseX(event),
        y: mouseY(event)
      };
      follower.style.top = mouse.y + 'px';
      return follower.style.left = mouse.x + 'px';
    };
  })(this);

  timer = false;

  window.onmousemove = init = (function(_this) {
    return function(event) {
      var _event;
      _event = event;
      return timer = setTimeout(function() {
        return positionElement(_event);
      }, 1);
    };
  })(this);

}).call(this);
```

```css
html {
  cursor: none;
  background: #666;
  height: 5000px;
}
#follower {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
#follower #circle1 {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 2s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 0em;
  width: 0em;
  margin-top: 0em;
  margin-left: 0em;
}
#follower #circle2 {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 4s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: pulse 4s infinite;
  background: rgba(200,0,0,0.8);
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 0em;
  width: 0em;
  margin-top: 0em;
  margin-left: 0em;
}
@-moz-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.9;
    height: 3em;
    width: 3em;
    margin-top: -1.5em;
    margin-left: -1.5em;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.9;
    height: 3em;
    width: 3em;
    margin-top: -1.5em;
    margin-left: -1.5em;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.9;
    height: 3em;
    width: 3em;
    margin-top: -1.5em;
    margin-left: -1.5em;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
  }
}
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.9;
    height: 3em;
    width: 3em;
    margin-top: -1.5em;
    margin-left: -1.5em;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Link</a>
<div id="follower">
  <div id="circle1"></div>
  <div id="circle2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great for the text link @michaelCoker but if I was to use an image in the anchor it puts the cursor behind that

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent your normal cursor from showing when above the link then you can add the following lines to your script:

```
  clickElement = (function(_this) {
    return function(event) {
      var mouse;
      mouse = {
        x: mouseX(event),
        y: mouseY(event)
      };

      var followerDisplay = follower.style.display;
      follower.style.display = "none";
      var elementAtCursor = document.elementFromPoint(mouse.x, mouse.y);
      follower.style.display = followerDisplay;
      elementAtCursor.click();
    };
  })(this);

  window.onmouseup = (function(_this) {
    return function(event) {
      var _event;
      _event = event;
      return (timer = setTimeout(function() {
        return clickElement(_event);
      }, 1));
    };
  })(this);
```

On `mouseup` the position is obtained, then the `follower` element is rendered `display: none` in order to get the element at position using `document.elementFromPoint(x, y)` then `follower` gets its `display` property back.

The downside (or not if it pleases you) is that the animation is restarted.

So in order to keep the animation running you can use `visibility` instead:

```
  follower.style.visibility = "hidden";
  var elementAtCursor = document.elementFromPoint(mouse.x, mouse.y);
  follower.style.visibility = 'visible';
  elementAtCursor.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems a little hacky but it works.

## JS

```
(function() {
  var follower, init, mouseX, mouseY, positionElement, printout, timer;

  follower = document.getElementById('follower');

  printout = document.getElementById('printout');

  mouseX = (function(_this) {
    return function(event) {
      return event.clientX;
    };
  })(this);

  mouseY = (function(_this) {
    return function(event) {
      return event.clientY;
    };
  })(this);

  positionElement = (function(_this) {
    return function(event) {
      var mouse;
      mouse = {
        x: mouseX(event),
        y: mouseY(event)
      };
      follower.style.top = mouse.y + 'px';
      return follower.style.left = mouse.x + 'px';
    };

  })(this);

  $('#follower').on('mousedown', function(){
    // Hide the #follower element
    $(this).hide(); 

    // Set the hover event on anchor tags so this immediately gets called if we're over an anchor tag
    $('a').on('mouseover', function(){
      $(this).click(); // Click the anchor tag
      $('#follower').show(); // Show the #follower element again
    })
  });

  // Unbind the anchor tag mouseover event so we don't click anchor tags by moving the mouse quickly
  $(document).on('mouseover', function() {
    $('a').unbind('mouseover').show();
  })
  
  timer = false;

  window.onmousemove = init = (function(_this) {
    return function(event) {
      var _event;
      _event = event;
      return timer = setTimeout(function() {
        return positionElement(_event);
      }, 1);
    };
  })(this);

}).call(this);
```

I added this section:

```
$('#follower').on('mousedown', function(){
    // Hide the #follower element
    $(this).hide(); 

    // Set the hover event on anchor tags so this immediately gets called if we're over an anchor tag
    $('a').on('mouseover', function(){
      $(this).click(); // Click the anchor tag
      $('#follower').show(); // Show the #follower element again
    })
});

// Unbind the anchor tag mouseover event so we don't click anchor tags by moving the mouse quickly
$(document).on('mouseover', function() {      
    $('a').unbind('mouseover').show();
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Thats because Link is lower then the circles. So you are actually clicking the circle. Add css z-index lower then the link or however you want to fix but the issue is with z-index.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PmpQzg

```
#follower {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why its down-voted? Problem is identified with demo. @stackoverflow needs to review such down votes :@